# My Spyder console cannot recognize pygal once I import it

Tags: python, spyder, pygal

[spyder console text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyXiC.png)

[python cmd - pygal working normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Glng.png)

However, when I open, for example, on CMD or on Python IDLE, pygal is imported normally.

I moved all my projects and Spyder to the same directory where python3 is installed.

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVCkt.png)

Does anybody have any idea what possibly can be going on? Getting the error 
 message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal'.

Comment: Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the installation command in the Spyder itself if you did not.
This is probably happening because pygal was installed in a different conda or venv/virtualenv environment than the one in which Spyder is currently running. The other day I also faced the same problem while importing a package. I ran the installation command in the command line. And it was installed but I could not access it from Spyder. However, when I ran the installation command from the Spyder and it executed. I was able to import it. I hope this helps. Give this [Working with packages and environments in Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) article a read. It explains similar problem.